# Qt proper project structure for testing

Tags: c++, qt

I am currently in the process of setting up QTests for my Qt project and I am struggling a bit to come up with a nice structure which fullfills my needs.
Atm the project looks like this:

```
.
├── keygen
│   ├── main.cpp
│   ├── tests
│   │   ├── passkeygen_tests.cpp
│   │   └── tests.pri
├── common.pri
├── MainApp
│   ├── mainapp.pro
│   ├── main.cpp
├── TestProject.pro
├── lib_utils
│   ├── utils.cpp
│   ├── lib_utils.pro
```

The TestProject is a subproject pro file containing info about keygen(standalone executable), MainApp and libutils (used by MainApp). As you can see I already added tests for the keygen according to what I saw in this example https://github.com/kelvins/CodeCoverageExampleQt/tree/master/CodeCoverageExample because I want to see the testcoverage of my subprojects. So the files look like this:
keygen.pro:

```
include($$PWD/../common.pri)

QT += core dbus testlib

TEMPLATE = app
DESTDIR = $${OUT_PWD}/bin
TARGET = keygen

include($$PWD/tests/tests.pri)
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += --coverage
QMAKE_LFLAGS += --coverage
```

tests.pri:

```
SOURCES += $$PWD/passkeygen_tests.cpp
```

passkeygen_tests.cpp:

```
#include <QtTest>

#include "passkeygenerator.h"

class PasskeygenTester : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

private:
    PasskeyGenerator passkeygen;

private slots:
    void checkGeneration();
    void checkGeneration_data();

};
//Implementations
static PasskeygenTester passkeygenInstance;

#include "passkeygen_tests.moc"
```

This works in the sense that when I compile the project I see the *.gcno files are generated, but this way I can not execute the tests standalone to get the actual coverage. So my question is what is the best way to do generate gcov information and have standalone executable tests? The link from earlier only cared about executing the test not runnability of the actual project.

I created a sample project which highlights the struggle I am facing especially when it comes to tests for a library:https://github.com/faxe1008/TestCoverageStructureTest